# Dynamic Selected Dependence Dropdowns

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic, dropdown

Can you help me please with following:

My Code:

```
<select name="genform[praeferenz_1]" id="genform_praeferenz_1">
<option value="placeholder_1">Bitte wählen...</option>
<option value="rot_1">Rot</option>
<option value="weiss_1">Weiß</option>
<option value="gelb_1">Gelb</option>
<option value="blau_1">Blau</option>
</select><

<select name="genform[praeferenz_2]" id="genform_praeferenz_2">
<option value="placeholder_2">Bitte wählen...</option>
<option value="rot_2">Rot</option>
<option value="weiss_2">Weiß</option>
<option value="gelb_2">Gelb</option>
<option value="blau_2">Blau</option>
</select>

<select name="genform[praeferenz_3]" id="genform_praeferenz_3">
<option value="palceholder_3">Bitte Trikotfarbe wählen...</option>
<option value="rot_3">Rot</option>
<option value="weiss_3">Weiß</option>
<option value="gelb_3">Gelb</option>
<option value="blau_3">Blau</option>
</select>

<select name="genform[praeferenz_4]" id="genform_praeferenz_4">
<option value="placeholder_4">Bitte wählen...</option>
<option value="rot_4">Rot</option>
<option value="weiss_4">Weiß</option>
<option value="gelb_4">Gelb</option>
<option value="blau_4">Blau</option>
</select>
```

If you have selected an option, the other options should be removed.

Example:

If I select "rot_1" in the first dropdown then rot_2, rot_3, rot_4 are not available in the following dropdowns.

Then when I choose gelb_2 in the second drobdown.

In the following dropdowns gelb_3 and gelb_4 are no longer available.

And so on....

Comment: edit: I cant change the HTML

Comment: edit: We can't help you until you show some coding effort to us what you tried to overcome your problem/requirement. SO is not a free coding platform service.

Comment: I know - i'm sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the following snippet as per your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "select", function() {
    var cur_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var cur_val = $(this).val();
    if (typeof cur_val != 'undefined' && cur_val != '') {
      subs = cur_val.substr(0, cur_val.indexOf('_'));
      $("select[id!='" + cur_id + "']").each(function() {
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
          //$(this).show();
          var cur_v = $(this).val();
          subst = cur_v.substr(0, cur_v.indexOf('_'));
          if (subs == subst) {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="genform[praeferenz_1]" id="genform_praeferenz_1">
  <option value="placeholder_1">Bitte wählen...</option>
  <option value="rot_1">Rot</option>
  <option value="weiss_1">Weiß</option>
  <option value="gelb_1">Gelb</option>
  <option value="blau_1">Blau</option>
</select>

<select name="genform[praeferenz_2]" id="genform_praeferenz_2">
  <option value="placeholder_2">Bitte wählen...</option>
  <option value="rot_2">Rot</option>
  <option value="weiss_2">Weiß</option>
  <option value="gelb_2">Gelb</option>
  <option value="blau_2">Blau</option>
</select>

<select name="genform[praeferenz_3]" id="genform_praeferenz_3">
  <option value="palceholder_3">Bitte Trikotfarbe wählen...</option>
  <option value="rot_3">Rot</option>
  <option value="weiss_3">Weiß</option>
  <option value="gelb_3">Gelb</option>
  <option value="blau_3">Blau</option>
</select>

<select name="genform[praeferenz_4]" id="genform_praeferenz_4">
  <option value="placeholder_4">Bitte wählen...</option>
  <option value="rot_4">Rot</option>
  <option value="weiss_4">Weiß</option>
  <option value="gelb_4">Gelb</option>
  <option value="blau_4">Blau</option>
</select>
```

The [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method returns the part of a string between the start index and a number of characters after it.

The [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. It would be perfect if the option also stays hidden when selecting the next option. At the end, only one selection left.

Comment: Once check output again. I made changes as per your requirement